# How can I concatenate data frames without losing brackets in column names?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) with these column names

```
 add (1 unit), add (2 unit), sub
```

second dataframe

```
 add1, sdd1h, Li2c
```

I combine these dataframes using

```
x <- data.frame(df1,df2)
```

But I am losing the names in df1, where it becomes `add.1.unit` in the new dataframe. How can I keep the column names as it is?

Note: I don't have to merge by row or anything. These are unrelated columns of same length that needs to be in the same dataframe

Comment: Maybe try `cbind` or `df1[names(df2)] <- df2` to edit one table into the other.

Comment: Ah....Thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `check.names=FALSE` when combining the data frames:

```
x <- data.frame(df1, df2, check.names=FALSE)
```